# Sorting by sheet name

Tags: excel, vba

below is the macro code which i am using for sorting the sheet name. but i am getting error Getting

> Run time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method".

Can some please help me to resolve this issue.

Sort by sheet name and number <>

```
Range("B2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select 
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("C2:C" + CStr(ShCount)) _
,SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("D2:D" + CStr(ShCount)) _
, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
.SetRange Range("B2:D" + CStr(ShCount))
.Header = xlGuess
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With
Range("B2").Select
```

Here is the error window:

[image: Here is the error window]

And here is the code error highlighted in yellow.

[image: Error code]